# Flipping Coins: Sequences vs Independent Flips

Tags: probability, fractions, percentages, simulation

Here is a problem I thought of:

- Suppose I am watching someone flip a fair coin. Each flip is completely independent from the previous flip.
- I watch this person flip 3 consecutive heads.
- I interrupt this person and ask the following question: If the next flip results in a "head", I will buy you a slice of pizza. If the next flip results in a "tail", you will buy me a slice of pizza.

**My Question:** Who has the better odds of winning?

I wrote the following simulation using the R programming language. In this simulation, a "coin" is flipped many times ("1" = HEAD, "0" = TAILS). We then count the percentage of times HEAD-HEAD-HEAD-HEAD appears compared to HEAD-HEAD-HEAD-TAILS:

```
#load library
library(stringr)

#define number of flips
n <- 10000000 

#flip the coin many times
flips = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n)

#count the percent of times HEAD-HEAD-HEAD-HEAD appears 
str_count(paste(flips, collapse=""), '1111') / n

0.0333663

#count the percent tof times HEAD-HEAD-HEAD-TAIL appears
str_count(paste(flips, collapse=""), '1110') / n

0.062555
```

From the above analysis, it appears as if the person's luck runs out: after 3 HEADS, there is a 3.33% chance that the next flip will be a HEAD compared to a 6.25% chance the next flip will not be a HEAD (i.e. TAILS).

Thus, could we conclude: Even though the probability of each flip is independent from the previous flip, it becomes statistically more advantageous to observe a sequence of HEADS and then bet the next flip will be a TAILS? Thus, the longer the sequence of HEADS you observe, the stronger the probability becomes of the sequence "breaking"?

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544382/flipping-coins-probability-of-sequences-vs-probability-of-individuals

Answer (score 3):

You are misled by a technical issue: it looks like the `str_count` command in R counts the number of *non-overlapping* matches it finds. Therefore it will not correctly count all the times that three flips of "heads" are followed by a fourth.

For example, in the sequence

```
11111101110
```

(where `1` represents "heads" and `0` represents "tails"), the `str_count` command will tell you that `1111` only appears once, but `1110` appears twice. But in fact, if you look at the five times that `111` appears in the string (including overlaps), then it is followed by another `1` *three* times, and by `0` only twice.

Over many coin-flips, if you count all instances of `1111` or `1110` and allow overlaps, you should see each one about $\frac1{16} = 0.0625$ of the time. So three "heads" are equally likely to be followed by "heads" or "tails".

(Note that this does not mean that after three "heads", there is a $0.0625$ probability of "heads" and a $0.0625$ probability of "tails": there is a $\frac12$ probability of each. The $0.0625$ counts the probability of all four flips happening.)